# Show When Applications Were Opened and Closed

Tags: macos, applications, script, console

I'd like to be able to see a list of applications that were recently opened and quitted on a per user basis.

Ex:

- `19:25:34 Google Chrome Canary opened by John Smith`
- `20:45:32 Pages quitted by Julie Smith`

I checked the Console, but it didn't seem to specifically detail when apps were opened/quitted and by whom; it only detailed the processes that errored in those applications.

Is there a way (eg. a script I can run) that will show all applications opened and quitted within a certain time frame, and by whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on [auditing](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/category/openbsm/).

```
man audit
```

Comment: Okay. I took a look at the `man` file and wasn't quite sure...what would I run specifically to turn on auditing and later access its findings?

Comment: Yes, it's not really straightforward, pls follow the link in my answer, that provides more context for OpenBSM auditing.